# tkinter key binding not fully working on Raspberry pi

Tags: python, tkinter

I wrote a code on my windows machine with python 3.7 TKinter, I bound the enter button to my function and all works great. The main enter key works, along with the number pad enter key.

I loaded the code onto my raspberry pi 3b, and the number pad enter key no longer call my function, but the main keyboard enter key does.

```
root.bind("<Return>", (lambda event: say_hello()))
```

Is there a way to make this work with both enter keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    root.bind("<Return>", (lambda event: say_hello()))
```

This refers to the Return key, while

```
    root.bind("<KP_Enter>", (lambda event: say_hello()))
```

works for the Enter key, to know more about tkinter bindings, you can refer to the following [link](https://www.goingthewongway.com/tkinter-keyboard-bindings-in-python/).